# UART and Max10?

Tags: uart, pins, max10

I am searching the datasheets of the Max10 FPGA family from Intel, but I just can not find the information that I am looking for or I have a misunderstanding.

My question: I want to create a UART -> USB connection using the FT2232H IC for interacting with a computer. The same ic also provides JTAG, which I already connected to the specific pins on the fpga. Are there any specific pins for a UART interface at the fpga or can I just use any pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an FPGA. You can have an UART on as many pins as you like until you run out of logic elements.

Comment: okay, that is what I thought =) Thank you very much for confirming!